# Root password for default Turtlebot install

Tags: ros, installation, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I bought a Turtlebot assembled from Clearpath Robotics and it arrived today (yay!). It came with Ubuntu and ROS already configured, however, I don't know the root password.

Following the [set up instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/diamondback/Robot%20Setup), I logged in with turtlebot/turtlebot successfully. However, when needing root access (changing the Time Settings in the GUI, for example),  I'm prompted for the root user password. It's not "turtlebot" or "root".

I'm asking the question here instead of from Clearpath's support incase others run into the same issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10889/root-password-for-default-turtlebot-install/) by [baalexander](https://answers.ros.org/users/143/baalexander/) on ROS Answers with karma: 233 on 2011-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The user "turtlebot" has sudo access. I was able to change the root password with:

`sudo passwd`

---

Originally posted by [baalexander](https://answers.ros.org/users/143/baalexander/) with karma: 233 on 2011-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2